# Enabling Geodatabase from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase

I have created a sde schema in my PostgreSQL database, I check all the privileges and everything. I also put the st_geometry.so in lib path of PostgreSQL 9.1.3 installed on the server. I have ArcGIS 10.1

When I am trying to "enable geodatabase" from the database in ArcMap 10.1 I am getting these errors:

```
relation "sde.sde_layers" does not exist at character 22
STATEMENT:  select count(*) from work.sde.sde_layers

ERROR:  relation "sde.gdb_items" does not exist at character 15
STATEMENT:  select 1 FROM sde.GDB_ITEMS

ERROR:  function st_geometry_version() does not exist at character 8
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

STATEMENT:  SELECT ST_GEOMETRY_VERSION()::varchar
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql/lib/st_geometry.so": /usr/local/pgsql/lib/st_geometry.so: undefined symbol: DirectFunctionCall1

STATEMENT:  Create OR Replace FUNCTION public.ST_Geometry_Version() RETURNS text AS 'st_geometry', 'ST_Geometry_Version' LANGUAGE 'C' WITH (ISCACHABLE, ISSTRICT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library load failure is the only significant message.  The most likely
cause is failure to copy the PostgreSQL 9.1 support library from Desktop10.1\DatabaseSupport\PostgreSQL\9.1\Linux64 (Windows) or 
arcgis/server/DatabaseSupport/PostgreSQL/9.1/Linux64 (Linux).

The MD5sum from my 10.1sp1 st_geometry.so is 4a60a91c3ac1a3759880456fe723ab5f
(the 9.0 library md5sum is 984229154e8b6b670383a4ff3a9b42a7, and the 10.1 Final 9.0 library md5sum is 88883f2371a292e7e64879f572f2cd08)